# React - Map inside a map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm looking to create a simple multiplication table using React. I've got the following code where I'm trying to loop through an array.

```
{array.map((num) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <th>{num}</th>

      {array.map((x) => {
        return <td>{x}</td>;
      })}
    </tr>
  );
})}
```

I'm getting the error 'num.map is not a function'

I understand that num is not a function, but I wanted to check if there is a way I could basically create a nested loop? If not, my alternative would be to convert a string to JSX, but I wanted to check whether there's a way I could achieve this with map first.

Comment: `num.map` not not being call in the code you shared...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array.from()` to create a range of numbers, iterate them, and produce react nodes:

```js
const renderRange = (start, end, cb) => Array.from(
  { length: end - start + 1 },
  (_, i) => cb(i + start)
)

const Demo = () => (
  <table>
    <tbody>
      {renderRange(1, 10, x => (
        <tr key={x}>
          {renderRange(1, 10, y => (
            <td key={x * y}>
              {x * y}
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
)
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```